# Having difficulty with what seems like a standard integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am fairly sure the integral I am trying to evaluate has an analytical solution and I am not used to Mathematica not finding the answer relatively easily, I have tried out a few tricks and transformations but doesn't seem to evaluate it.

Here is the integral:

$$ F(x,y,z)=\int_{r=0}^{r=R} \int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=2\pi}dr \ d\phi \left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{(z-\delta)^2+(x-r \cos(\phi))^2+(y-r \sin(\phi))^2}}\right)-\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{(z+\delta)^2+(x-r \cos(\phi))^2+(y-r \sin(\phi))^2}}\right)$$

Here is the code I use for it with assumptions clarified on these parameters (everything is real)

```
Integrate[ r/Sqrt[(z - \[Delta])^2 + (x - r Cos[\[Phi]])^2 + (y - 
 r Sin[\[Phi]])^2] - r/  Sqrt[(z + \[Delta])^2 + (x - r Cos[\[Phi]])^2 + (y - 
 r Sin[\[Phi]])^2], {r, 0, R}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

I tried the integration with the following assumptions:

$ {x,y,z,R,\delta} \in \Re $ and $ R>0,\delta >0$.

Not sure if this is truly uncomputable or I am missing a simple transformation. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: The integral is zero if $\delta = 0$ assuming $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$. However neither Mathematica, nor [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org) can solve this one. You can however find anti-derivatives in $r$ alone (which will produce a horrible expression involving ArcTanh) and $\phi$ alone (which produces an even more horrible expression involving AppelF1).

Comment: Do the individual anti-derivatives (over phi or r) require Rubi or Mathematica? I am perhaps mistaken that this has known solutions.

Comment: Your code executes on MMA 12.1 Windows 10. It takes some minutes and 20GBytes RAM